# How to echo WP SEO Yoast synonyms in PHP?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I need to print a page including WPSEO informations, for translation. 
I am trying to output WPSEO information in PHP, and I have managed for title, description, focus kewords, but it does not work for synonyms (nothing comes out). 
There seems to be no Meta for synonym, so how to get it?

````
<div id="print-seo">
Title: "<?php echo WPSEO_Meta::get_value("title"); ?>"<br />
Description: "<?php echo WPSEO_Meta::get_value("metadesc"); ?>"<br />
Focus Keyword: "<?php echo WPSEO_Meta::get_value("focuskw"); ?>"<br />
Synonyms: "<?php echo WPSEO_Meta::get_value("synonyms"); ?>"<br />
</div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

I found the meta_key in wp_postmeta table is _yoast_wpseo_keywordsynonyms, so I could end up with this and it works:

````
Title: "<?php echo WPSEO_Meta::get_value("title"); ?>"<br />
Description: "<?php echo WPSEO_Meta::get_value("metadesc"); ?>"<br />
Focus Keyword: "<?php echo WPSEO_Meta::get_value("focuskw"); ?>"<br />
Synonyms: "<?php echo substr(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_keywordsynonyms', true ), 2, -5); ?>"<br />
</div>```
````